# What happened when I wrote "a, b, c = [[],] * 3" in python? It seems that a, b, c are the same object

Tags: python

What happened when I wrote `a, b, c = [[],] * 3` in python?
It seems that `a`, `b`, `c` are the same object.

```py
a, b, c = [[],] * 3
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
print(c)
```

The answer is `[1,2]` , why?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `*` operator just creates copies of the same list `[]` three times, not three fresh lists.

So, `a`, `b`, `c` all point to the same list. And you added `1` and `2` to both.

---

This:

```py
a, b, c = [[] for _ in range(3)]
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
print(c)
```

would give you `[]` as expected.

Comment: copy of object mean, creating a altogether new object with same value. in this case it's not copy it's is reference, 3 object are created which are referenced to same object

Comment: It **is** a copy of the pointer!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "reference". The underlying semantics is that of copying pointers -- which point to the same memory location.